# Prove that $\{\frac{1}{n^3}\}^{\infty}_{n = 1}$ is Cauchy?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, cauchy-sequences

To prove that $\frac{1}{n^3}$ is Cauchy you apply $\big|a_n-a_m\big|$ so it looks like $\big|\frac{1}{n^3} - \frac{1}{m^3}\big|$ but then you have to do something before applying the triangle rule and I'm not sure what.

Apparently $\big|\frac{1}{n^3}\big| + \big|\frac{1}{m^3}\big|<\epsilon \Rightarrow \frac{\epsilon}{2}=\frac{1}{N^3}\Rightarrow N=\big\lceil\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{\epsilon}}\big\rceil$ is wrong.

Comment: $\frac{1}{n^3}$ converges to 0 hence is Cauchy.

Comment: Hi Luke, Do you know the following *Result*: A sequence(Real or complex) is convergent if and only if the sequence is a Cauchy sequence? Can you apply this to formulate your answer?

Comment: Not meant to be answering it using such a proof at this time, thank you for the suggestion and I will look into it later.

Comment: Small n is any number in the sequence ie. $a_1 = \frac{1}{(1)^3}$ and so on, where $a_m$ is the next in the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original approach will work provided $n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{0\}$.

Given any $\epsilon>0$, you would like to find an $N$ such that for any $n,m>N$, $\left|\frac{1}{n^3}-\frac{1}{m^3}\right|<\epsilon$. This would certainly be the case if $\frac{1}{n^3},\frac{1}{m^3}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ since $\left|\frac{1}{n^3}-\frac{1}{m^3}\right|\leq\left|\frac{1}{n^3}\right|+\left|\frac{1}{m^3}\right|$. Therefore you need to force $n,m>\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{\epsilon}}$. Conveniently enough, you are allowed to choose whichever $N$ you like, so choosing $N>\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{\epsilon}}$ will do the trick. The above constitutes the work you do beforehand, now the proof.

Claim: The sequence $\{\frac{1}{n^3}\}$ is Cauchy.

Proof: Let $\epsilon>0$ be given and let $N>\sqrt[3]{\frac{2}{\epsilon}}$. Then for any $n,m>N$, one has $0<\frac{1}{n^3},\frac{1}{m^3}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Therefore, $\epsilon>\frac{1}{n^3}+\frac{1}{m^3}=\left|\frac{1}{n^3}\right|+\left|\frac{1}{m^3}\right|\geq\left|\frac{1}{n^3}-\frac{1}{m^3}\right|$. Thus, the sequence is Cauchy as was to be shown.

Comment: Was about to write a proof using the definition of a Cauchy sequence but you were quicker :). +1 for detailed solution.

Answer (score 0):

On the real line $\mathbb{R}$ you have the following

Theorem. A sequence converges if and only if it is Cauchy.

So if you can show that the sequence $\frac{1}{n^{3}}$ converges, then you are done.

You have some options now. Either show directly by the definition of convergence, that the sequence converges to a point, in this case $0$. Or notice that $\frac{1}{n} = n^{-3} = n^{-1} n^{-1} n^{-1}$ and show first that $n^{-1} = \frac{1}{n}$ converges to a point, in this case $0$.

Comment: The theorem holds true for $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Yes but I think that it is assumed that $n \in \mathbb{N} \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

Comment: Probably your and OP's assumption might be coherent. But OP's post doesn't clarify what is $n$; so, it's maybe better to state the assumption(it avoids downvotes :) ). Anyway, for $n=0$, the sequence doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Kumar Yes I agree. But "usually" $n, m$ stand for natural numbers and often $\mathbb{N} = \{ 1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$ is used for natural numbers instead of $\mathbb{N} = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots \}$. Also in mathematics we must know from context what the underlying assumptions are, i.e. for what natural number the sequence makes sense. This context knowing leads (sadly) to confusion as you remarked.

Comment: Yeh within the context of Cauchy sequences n is normally just a number in $\mathbb N$. Sorry for confusion.